# c++ bool While on vector

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

I'm new in c++, so this is maybe something usual.

I have a `std::vector<int> v;`

And I want to see if is 0 in this vector. I think this is working:

```
bool l = true;
    i = 0;
    while((l = true) && (i<v.size()))
    {
        if (v[i] == 0) l = false;
        ++i;
    }
```

But even if my vector is 1,2,3,0,2,0 this `l` remains `true`. Why? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c++
while((l = true) && (i<v.size()))
```

is actually an assignment. You should write more safe comparison code

```c++
while((true == l) && (i<v.size())
```

Notice that in this case if you accidentally type `=`  instead of `==` there will be a compilation error instead of broken code.

Comment: You should do neither. Just write `while (l && ...)` instead of explicitly comparing to `true`.

Comment: Actually there is no need in `l` at all, writing `if(0 == v[i]) {break;}` would do the thing. But I want to point out safe comparison with constant.

Comment: @VTT: Ew, Yoda. It's not 4th May any more!

Comment: Too many parentheses, regardless of which variant you prefer.